# Ubuntu 20.04 - Open Terminal for automatic MQTT subsribe after login

Tags: boot, command-line

I wish that after login to subscribe MQTT topic. In terminal I write: `mosquitto_sub -u "USR" -P "PWD" -h "192.168.3.200" -t "myHome/Messages"`.

Appreciate guidance

Comment: @user535733 - yes, you are right. Question was revised

Comment: Please clarify. What is MQTT? Does the terminal need to stay open after login?

Comment: @vanadium - yes its is shows messages on terminal ( its a communication protocol ).

Comment: Can you open it in a separate terminal with the terminal command `gnome-terminal -- mosquitto_sub -u "USR" -P "PWD" -h "192.168.3.200" -t "myHome/Messages"`? If yes, simply add such command to your autostart applications.

Comment: @vanadium OK, it works. How can I create several connection ( diffrent tabs ) ?

Comment: That sounds like a different question.

Comment: @vanadium - it may be... I tried to create several instances / tabs without any lucj